# programatic approach of schema update in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, database-schema

the way we apply schema update is like this:

- wrap every SQL into a string
- create a update object, which takes the SQL, a version id, and another string "update reason "
- suppose we have 100 updates, each one will be created, and save into a list
- then loop through the list compare the version id with the current version id saved in the database, the update will be applied only if it above the current version.

the problem is we have more then 4000 lines of code in this class.

most of the updates have been done a few years ago, I hate to load them every time

is there a better way to do it in java?

Comment: I think you mean 'batch update' when you say 'schema update'. Also who provides the sql and the id and the reason parameters/ I guess you read them from a file?

Comment: all the parameters are hardcoded into class

Comment: The term for what you're doing is "database migration". There's a lot of libraries that handle this. One of them is [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) which has a table comparing the features of about ten libraries that do this on the homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a ton of tools out there that do this. Having looked at a bunch, I ended up going with [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org). The changes are stored in files, which, btw, can then also be versioned, and if you are using either github or bitbucket, people will see them as they go in, and can comment, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the sql into files instead in the java code.  The file naming strategy of the sql files could have the version and update reason as part of the file name or you could put the reason in the file.  The code would loop thru the files in the directory and add them to a list and then process as you normally would.

Comment: you answer is what I have designed myself, very NICE but rollback is a bit of difficult for this model